# unique array out of duplicated array in c++ without using STL

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, unique

I have an integer array of duplicated values

```
int array[] = {111, 111, 222, 333, 111, 444, 555, 111};
```

Out of the above array, I want to assign the unique values to the indexed vector array named **vectorArray**

Desired vectorArray values:

```
vectorArray[0] // 111
vectorArray[1] // 222
vectorArray[2] // 333
vectorArray[3] // 444
vectorArray[4] // 555
```

How would I go about it?

Comment: Many approaches come to mind.... is sorting the array an option? Or you could shove the values into a std::set, or you could put them into a std::unordered_set and get them back out.

Comment: You would  create an algo, write code and then make it work (debugging and testing)

Comment: @AndyG, thanks for your reply. I was not allowed to use std::set. I'm new to C++. If in php, it would have been easy: loop the array and index it's value to the vector. But C++ rings the "Out of range" bell